# How to play and stop audio whenever we click on button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, audio

I have a button in which `onClick` method is attached which will play a `vibaration` sound.

**Button.js**

```
import React from "react";
import "./button.css";

export default function App() {
  let audio = new Audio("/vibrate.mp3");

  const start = () => {
    audio.play();
  };

  return (
    <button className="btn" onClick={start}>
      Click Me
    </button>
  );
}
```

Vibration sound is playing whenever we click on button. But if I click button again then it is not playing vibration sound because previous sound is not completed yet.
I want to stop the sound (if playing) and play from start if we click on button.

You can check my [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/broken-rgb-106oz?file=/src/component/Button.js:0-265) .

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to stop the audio...

```
import React from "react";
import "./button.css";

export default function App() {
  let audio = new Audio("/vibrate.mp3");

  const start = () => {
    if(audio.paused === true){
      audio.play();
    }else{
      audio.pause();
      audio.currentTime = 0;
      audio.play();
    }
    
  };

  return (
    <button className="btn" onClick={start}>
      Click Me
    </button>
  );
}
```